# Missing FK Relationship in Entity Framework Model

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I had a lot of trouble implementing the technique described in an [Alexander Kuznetsov article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2011/10/17/trusted-foreign-keys-allow-orphans-reject-valid-child-rows.aspx). Basically, the article describes a way to create a FK between one table and *alternate* tables, and still maintain full constraints on those relationship.

Here's part of Alexander's code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vehicles(
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    [Type] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Vehicles_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT Vehicles_UNQ_ID_Type UNIQUE(ID, [Type]),
    CONSTRAINT Vehicles_CHK_ValidTypes CHECK([Type] IN ('Car', 'Truck'))
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Cars(ID INT NOT NULL,
    [Type] AS CAST('Car' AS VARCHAR(5)) PERSISTED,
    OtherData VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Cars_PK PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT Cars_FK_Vehicles FOREIGN KEY(ID, [Type])
    REFERENCES dbo.Vehicles(ID, [Type])
)
```

I finally got it working after errors and confirmed bugs. But when I generate my EF models from the new schema, it is missing a relationship between two of my tables.

The problem is that, in order to have a FK on two columns, there *must* be an index or unique constraint on *both* those columns. However, in my case, I also have another table with a FK to a single column in the base table (Vehicles, in Alexander's code).

Since you cannot have more than one PK in a table, this means I cannot have a FK to a PK on both sides. The PK can be for one or two columns, and the other FK will need to reference the non-PK unique constraint.

Unfortunately, Entity Framework will only create relationships for you when there is a FK to a PK. That's the problem. Can someone who understand DB design better than I spot any other alternatives here?

*Note: I realize some will see the obvious fix as simply modifying the model to manually add the additional relationship. Unfortunately, we are using a database project and are constantly using automated systems to regenerate the project and model from an updated database. So manual steps are really not practical.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more than one PK, but you can have more than one unique constraint, and in SQL Server you can create a foreign key constraint that references a unique constraint (one or multiple columns). Here is an example of two tables that roughly look like your model.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Vehicles
(
    VehicleID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [Type] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT u1 UNIQUE(VehicleID, [Type])
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Cars
(
    CarID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    VehicleID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Vehicles(VehicleID),
    [Type] VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Vehicles([Type]),
    CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (VehicleID, [Type])
        REFERENCES dbo.Vehicles(VehicleID, [Type])
);
```

Note that Cars has three foreign keys: one points to the PK of vehicles (VehicleID), one points to the unique constraint on Vehicles([Type]), and one points to the multi-column unique constraint on Vehicles(VehicleID, [Type]). I realize this is not equivalent to what you are trying to do but should demonstrate that SQL Server, at least, is capable of doing everything you seem to want to do (I'm having a hard time concluding what you're actually because you keep swapping concepts between what Alex did, what you're trying to do but failing, and what you've done successfully).

Are you saying that EF will not recognize a foreign key that references a unique constraint? If so, does that affect constraints that have more than one column, or all unique constraints? If this is the case, that's a shame, because it is certainly supported in SQL Server. Seems like this would either be a bug or an intentional omission (given that the standard doesn't strictly allow FKs against unique constraints). I wonder if there are any bugs reported on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/)?

I have no idea how to force EF to recognize it, but I do know that just about all the people I know who use database projects end up performing pre- or post-deployment modifications and these can be relatively automated.

Comment: Yes, I am using a unique constraint and that works in the database. But EF only establishes a relationship in the model when the FK references a PK. It *is* a shame. Perhaps it can be automated, but that would require considerable time (I'm not sure what is needed) and seems problematic all around.

Comment: Seems like this bug has been reported, but has been closed as a duplicate (no reference to the duplicate though) with the suggestion to add the FK to the model manually in the meantime (and also no indication of if / when they might try to fix it). You may want to add a comment asking for an update and explaining your use case. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/628107/edm-silently-ignores-foreign-key#details

Comment: Looks like it is a confirmed bug. I thought it was perhaps by design. I was hoping for some other arrangement that would do what I need where this won't be a problem but, ugh!, looks like this is the second confirmed bug I ran across trying to implement this schema.